# Login-AzureRmAccount return subscription but Get-AzureSubscription return empty

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

I am able to login successfully with the `Login-AzureRmAccount`. Also I am able to see my subscription in the return value of Login-AzureRmAccount. But after login, if I type `Get-AzureSubscription` it return empty.

Find the below screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, you need to use `Get-AzureRmSubscription` (RM), since you are using the cmdlet for ASM mode, not ARM.

There are 2 deployment modes in Azure, ASM (old) and ARM (new one).

Comment: is there a 3rd one now because Get-AzureRmSubscription returns nothing for me. I do see for other similar commands like Get-AzureADSubscribedSku

Answer (score 8):

Expanding on the other answers.

In Azure there is two deployment models. Azure Service Management (ASM) and Azure Resource Manager (ARM).

To interact with anything in ASM, you utilise the Azure Module, For Example:

`Add-AzureAccount` **Logs into ASM**

`Select-AzureSubscription` **Selects the Subscription you allocate to work within**

`Get-AzureSubscriptions` **Shows you all subscriptions**

To interact with anything in ARM, you utilise the AzureRM Modules, For Example:

`Add-AzureRmAccount` **Logs into ARM**

`Select-AzureRmSubscription` **Selects the ARM Subscription you allocate to work within**

`Login-AzureRmAccount` **Logs into ARM Also**

[ARM PowerShell Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azureps-cmdlets-docs/)

[ASM PowerShell Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/servicemanagement/)