# Trying to Log in to Azure in Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

I am following the MS guide located [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-6.3.0) and everything goes through correctly until I have to actually log in. The pop up window appears for my creds and validates them, but powershell doesn't seem to notice.

So it goes Install Module, Import Module, Verify Version, Log in. See below for what happens on the last two steps.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Module AzureRM -ListAvailable | Select-Object -Property Name,Version,Path

Name    Version Path
----    ------- ----
AzureRM 6.3.0   C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureRM\6.3.0\AzureRM.psd1


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Connect-AzureRmAccount


Account          :
SubscriptionName :
SubscriptionId   :
TenantId         :
Environment      :



PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Of course, this prevents me from doing very much else with Azure from that point forward.

Edit: Issue appears on multiple workstations

Comment: There is no value in the `Account`, `SubscriptionName`, etc?

Comment: That's right, it looks just as posted there.

Comment: Have you tried parsing the Credentials as an Object to the function? Like this `Connect-AzureRmAccount -Credential (Get-Credential)`

Comment: What's the ouput of Connect-AzureRmAccount -Debug ?

Comment: hey @Jeff are you able to able to login with your credentials through portal.azure.com? after you have imported the module and just type `Login-AzureRmAccount ` assuming it comes back with the similar to your question

Comment: Try to use `Logout-AzureRmAccount` again and again to logout the account until it throws`Logout-AzureRmAccount : Run Connect-AzureRmAccount to login.` Then try to login the account with `Connect-AzureRmAccount`.

Comment: Please try `Install-Module -Name AzureRM.profile` and then run `Remove-AzureRmAccount` to clear it up, and then connect with your Azure authenticated account Again.

Comment: @Paxz same result

Comment: @LachieWhite yes I can use portal.azure.com just fine.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT It throws the message after the first command. Same result when trying to log back in

Comment: @NancyXiong-MSFT Ran through this but same result afterward

Comment: I tried the process on another computer now, but I'm still getting the same thing. This makes me wonder if it could be related to my account...would be nice if it gave me a specific error though.

Comment: @Jeff never seen this happen before but I don’t believe there is a permission for PowerShell azure access. You are sure that your azure subscriptions are ARM and not ASM?

Comment: @Jeff added an answer id be keen for you to test out

Comment: can you just try azure powershell docker image to verify if its your account or your powershell (or just try another pc\vm)

Comment: @LachieWhite necro posting but yes it is ARM, if logging in through portal.azure.com is any indication.

Answer (score 3):

I got this same issue. I have two users like many of you: the Azure user that is the "**Work**" account, and then the "**Personal**" account which is also created automatically by Office365 and Azure. I was getting the issue when I tried to use my "personal" account, in which I have some subscriptions added (delegated).

After trying lots, what worked for me was to login to the "Work" account when the "Connect-AzureRmAccount" command asks for an username/password. Then, I again use the command "Connect-AzureRMAccount", but this time I entered the personal account, and it finally worked.

[Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnmFm.png)

Edit: A better way I found later was this, as I manage a lot of subscriptions/tenants from a single account (delegated access):

Put the “tenantid” into a variable (you can get this ID on the Azure Portal, in my case, on the option to change directories):

[How to get your tenant's IDs quickly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aizKM.png)

**$tenantId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"**

Login specifying the TenantId:
**Login-AzureRmAccount -TenantId $tenantId**

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4zNL.png)

Comment: This is great information but unfortunately these methods did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior happens when you run

```
Clear-AzureRMContext  -Scope CurrentUser
```

I'm not sure why and im attempting to debug  on how to fix the issue.  A work around is to close the powershell window and reopen a new powershell windows that does not have this command ran.

---

Running the command

```
Enable-AzureRmContextAutosave -Scope CurrentUser
```

Fixed the issue for me.  This will autosave your context  for every powershell session.  If this is not desired you can run the command

```
Enable-AzureRmContextAutosave -Scope Process
```

which will save the azure context for only the process. Otherwise you will need to handle

Answer (score 1):

You can try this...

```
Install-Module PoweshellGet -Force

Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExicutionPolicy Remotesigned 

Install-Module AzureRm

Import-Module -Name AzureRm
Login-AzureRmAccount
```

Comment: No luck here. Note for others "-ExicutionPolicy" here should be "-ExecutionPolicy" of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below link to install latest PowerShell version:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases

And then use something like this in order to automatically pass in the username password, and skipping the UI:

```
$azureAccountName ="enter username here"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "password here" -AsPlainText -Force

$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAccountName, $azurePassword)

Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $psCred
```

Comment: On the first step:

"Unexpected token '$azurePassword' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken"

Comment: Running PS 5.1, no luck

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following:

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Powershell.Security

$azureAccountName ="enter username here"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "password here" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAccountName, $azurePassword)

$decrypt = $psCred.GetNetworkCredential()
$ptpass = $decrypt.Password
Write-Output "Logging in to Azure using $azureAccountName with a password of $ptpass"

Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $psCred
```

If you receive an error with this code, please comment with the entire error message.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing i can think of is the below

You maybe using Azure Service Management (Azure V1 / Azure Classic) which uses a different module to Azure Resource Manager (ARM , Azure V2).

**To install Azure Service Management Module:**
`Install-Module Azure -AllowClobber`
*Allowing clobber because you already have AzureRM Module installed*

**Import Azure Module to PowerShell:**
`Import-Module Azure`

**Logs into ASM:**
`Add-AzureAccount`

**Shows you all subscriptions**
`Get-AzureSubscriptions`

**Selects the Subscription you allocate to work within**
`Select-AzureSubscription`

Answered something similar in the below Thread:
[Login-AzureRmAccount return subscription but Get-AzureSubscription return empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42390221/login-azurermaccount-return-subscription-but-get-azuresubscription-return-empty/42390768#42390768)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try logging in using the Service Principal credentials.

Service principal is an application created under Active Directory to which you can apply permission rules.

```
$pscredential = Get-Credential
Connect-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -ApplicationId  "http://my-app" -Credential $pscredential -TenantId $tenantid
```

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/authenticate-azureps?view=azurermps-6.4.0) for more details.